# How vscade automatically formats when saving is only applicable to HTML files

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

The following settings will be formatted when any file is saved.

I just need to format the HTML file when it is saved

```json
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :-

```
{
   "editor.formatOnSave": false,
   "[html]": {
       "editor.formatOnSave": true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can globally disable VSCode Format On Save altogether and enable it for only a handful of programming languages ( [identifiers for languages](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) ).

[Referance from.](https://linuxpip.org/vscode-format-on-save/)

so for HTML, check below,

```
{
   "editor.formatOnSave": false,
   "[html]": {
       "editor.formatOnSave": true
   }
}
```